# Understanding the chrome performance profile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've ran the JavaScript performance profiler on an application we're building, and I'm struggling to interpret one of the profiles I've got out, because it doesn't seem to match execution. I'm wondering am I reading this wrong? Or could this be a bug?

[image]

In this particular example the `_toggleLock` function appears to be called 3 times with differing times being recorded. I've looked at my code however, and this makes no sense. Here is my bablified code:

```
key: "_toggleLock",
value: function () {
   function _toggleLock() {
      console.log("toggleLock called");
      this.container.moveSiblingsBehind();
      ...
   }
},
```

The output of my console during that trace confirms that it's only called the once.

[image]

This makes the stack shown in the profile view very confusing. Can anyone explain what I'm seeing?

Comment: It's just a bug. Normally the profiler joins CPU samples into contiguous blocks.

Comment: Logged a bug for now https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=805833&can=2&q=call%20stack&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Looked in isolation it does not make sense. However the stack originates from a Timer Fired, which also has a little red flag on the top right corner. Click or hover that flag to see the message. What does it say? Additionally, take a look at the red line in the FPS panel; what are the causes of that line (FPS <60)? DevTools is powerful when we are able to look at the whole picture. If I was you also I would look into external dependencies (sometimes jquery trigger a similar behavior) or if the behavior is observable in jsbin / jsfiddle or else